# Adding Class instance as a new Row in DataGridView (c#)

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, datagridview

I have a class say

```
[Serializable]
    public class Answer
    {
        [DisplayName("ID")]
        public string ID { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

and I have a datagridview with bounded columns to the  above class.

instances of this class Answer are created dynamically as and when required.
How do I update datagridview when each and every instance of class is created.

is it possible to do something of this sort.

```
dataGridView.Rows.Add(classInstance);
```

Thanks in Advance,
Amit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but not the way you do it.

You need to use databinding.

Something like the following should work:

```
var ds = new BindingList<Answer>();
dgv.DataSource = ds;
```

Now when you do:

```
ds.Add( new Answer { ... });
```

it will be added (as you wanted).

Comment: Is it possible to use serialized xml instead of class instance to achive this. I am deserializing the xml to class instance and updating the datagridview as you said.

Comment: @Amit Shah: I suggest you create another question.

Comment: After using this solution it blocks Sorting mechanism? How do I enable them.

Comment: @Amit Shah: You need something like a `SortableBindingList` then. One is here (http://www.martinwilley.com/net/code/forms/sortablebindinglist.html) but Google for some more.